# Asymptotics of Bessel functions in the discrete parameter

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions

Is there any information on the asymptotics of $J_n(z)$ as $n\to \pm\infty$ for fixed $z$ (real or imaginary)? I originally wanted to ask about the modified Bessel functions $I_n(z)$, but found out that this was equivalent for changing $z$ from real <--> imaginary.

I am looking at quantum wave packets for quantised solitons and have to examine the convergence of sums of the form
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} I_n(z)\, a^n\, b^{n^2}\ .
$$
Any help or references would be greately appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked in the NIST Handbook, section 10.19?

Comment: The link in NIST's DLMF for asymptotics with respect to the index of modified Bessel functions is here: http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.41.E1

Comment: Thanks both above (the online reference is good as I am away just now). The asymptotics there is good for the index $n\ge 0$ sum, but I need to check about the index $n <0$ bit.

Comment: But then $K_n(z)$ is related to $I_{-n}(z)$ so there is a good chance it works...

Answer (score 2):

From https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselI/11/
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty I_k(x)t^k = \exp\left(\frac{x}{2}\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)
\\
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty J_k(x)t^k = \exp\left(\frac{x}{2}\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)
$$
In particular, $I_k(x) \to 0$ as $k\to\infty$ faster than any power $t^k$.

Comment: Thanks - this does the a=1 case in the original post, and looks very nice.

Answer (score 1):

The most comprehensive general reference is G. N. Watson, Treatise on the theory of Bessel functions, multiple editions, the latest: Cambridge 1995. It contains the asymptotics you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks - I will order that as soon as I can (away now).